# Upgrade path from CRM 3 SBS to CRM 4 Workgroup Edition

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have been tasked with upgrading a customer's CRM installation from CRM 3 SBS to CRM 4 Workgroup edition running on a dedicated server.

**Current Situation**

*dc1.example.com*

Windows 2003 Small Business Server (Not R2)

- DC
- Exchange
- CRM V3 Small Business Edition
- SQL Server for CRM

**Target Situation**

*dc1.example.com*

- DC
- Exchange

*crm.example.com*

- CRM V4 Workgroup Edition
- SQL Server for CRM

**Notes**

- CRM 4 Workgroup Edition will not run on a Server 2003 DC (unless it is R2, which dc1 isn't).
- The upgrade strategy usually requires upgrading the v3 instance to v4. This isn't possible with the current install due to above issue.

So, is it possible to redeploy the SBS version of CRM3 to a non SBS server, so that I can then upgrade it to CRM v4 Workgroup edition? Normally CRM3 SBS will only run on the SBS server, but can this be bypassed for the purpose of upgrading or will CRM3 SBS refuse to install?

I did consider using the 90 day trial version of CRM3 Pro on the new server, and then upgrade the new instance of CRM3 Pro to CRM4 Workgroup, however it seems that [this is not possible](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35136621/transfer-ata-from-crm-30-professional-to--crm-40-workgroup.aspx) either.

Can anyone offer any guidelines or a documented upgrade path for this type of set up?

Edit: Just attempted to install CRM 3 SBS onto a development non SBS server, and the installer refuses to continue. The only option I can think of is for my customer to purchase Server 2003 R2 SBS, upgrade the server to that, then upgrade CRM 3 SBS to CRM 4 Workgroup, then redeploy CRM 4 workgroup to the new server. Surely there must be an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like I have any alternative but to upgrade the DC to R2, upgrade CRM to v4, move the databases to the new dedicated server, then remove CRM from the DC and install it again on the dedicated server.